# Using qrc file with TTF_OPENFONT()

Tags: c++, qt, resources

I'm trying to use qrc file (Qt Creator 2.7 & Mac OS X) to manage my resources but it won't work... Here's the path of my font copy/pasted from *Copy Resource Path to Clipboard* :

```
:/fonts/data/Arial.ttf
```

Here's the part where I use it :

```
TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont(":/fonts/data/Arial.ttf", 100);
```

And here's the result :

> Error (Font) :  Couldn't open :/fonts/test

But if I use the absolute path to the font, it works so the problem is not from TTF_OpenFont()

Comment: Are you on Windows? If you were on linux, I'd suggest using `"fonts/data/Arial.ttf"`. I know nothing of either QT or Windows, but usually when opening files in libraries it goes like that.

Comment: Oh I forget to mention it! I'm on Mac Os X

Comment: Both Linux and OS X are Unix-like, so I'd guess it's up to QT.

Comment: So do you have any clue?

Comment: Well, did the `"fonts/data/Arial.ttf"` work?

Comment: according you're talking of the absolute path, yes, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TTF_OpenFont` doesn't know anything about Qt's resource system, therefore it cannot open the file.

You could read the font file content from resource file using `QFile`, then save it to the disk to some temporary file and then open that file with `TTF_OpenFont`.

Comment: So :/fonts/data/Arial.ttf doesn't link to a file?

Comment: If so, do you know a way in Qt to link a file to an executable during compilation?

Comment: I don't quite understand what mean by "linking to a file", but when you put a file to Qt's resource system, the file is stored inside the executable. Because this is a Qt specific feature, the file cannot be accessed using normal C++ file routines because the file just doesn't exist as a normal file. The point using the resource system is to avoid deploying a lot of separate files, instead you can store icon files, sound files etc. inside the executable. But of course, you don't need to put all files you are using to the resources. Just deploy the ttf file with your executable as it is.

Comment: Well, I better understand what you mean, I'll check with deployment options! Thank you!